# parameterized enumerable type in elixir typespecs

Tags: types, elixir

Is it possible to parametrize the `Enumerable.t` type in elixir?

so currently I have a function that takes a list of `foo`s:

```
@spec the_awesome([foo]) :: any
def the awesome(foos) do
  Enum.reduce(foos, &(bar(&2, &1)))
end
```

and really it does not have to be a list! since the only function call is from the `Enum` module I'd like to change the typespec to take any Enumerable, but keep the requirement that the Enumerable must consist entirely of `foo`s

Something like

```
@spec the_awesome(Enumerable.t(foo)) :: any
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not right now. We would need to teach dialyzer how to handle protocols if we really want them to be expressive and there are no plans for doing such.